# Optimizing an inequality (Sum of two positive terms)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, optimization

A common trick in giving estimates is to let $R>0$ denote an undetermined positive constant, and choose it later so that it optimizes the bound. For example, in a proof of the Hardy Littlewood Sobolev inequality given in P.434 of Zygmund, the author begins by writing the Riesz potential as
\begin{align*}
I_\alpha f(x) = \int_{|x-y|<\delta} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}} dy +  \int_{|x-y|\geq \delta} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}} dy,
\end{align*}
then proceeds with calculations to obtain
$$I_\alpha f(x) \leq \delta^\alpha f^*(x) + \delta^{\alpha - n/p} \|f\|_p,$$
and finally chooses $\delta>0$ so that the two terms on the right-hand-side of the bound are equal. That is, we choose $\delta>0$ so that $\delta^\alpha f^*(x) = \delta^{\alpha - n/p} \|f\|_p$.

Alright, I've been using this trick for years, and I've always said (with my own mouth) that this is the way to optimize the given bound; but the other day, a friend of mine asked me if I could give a short proof as to why this procedure really optimizes the bound ; I could not answer him.

If I think of the AM-GM inequality, then it seems sensible that the sum of two positive numbers are minimized when the two are equal. But I cannot give a rigorous argument; in the general case where $f,g$ are non-negative functions, would $f(\delta)+g(\delta)$ always attain minimum only if $f(\delta) = g(\delta)$?

I would appreciate if someone could supply me a clean proof as to why this procedure is valid. Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made direct calculations with the AM-GM inequality and found that setting the two equal yields the optimal bound - but up to some constant C that depends only on the powers of $\delta.$